# Two similar animals

Tags: knowledge, language, anagram

Can you find the 2 similar animals that has it's names scrambled in this text?

> laneeatkajswliuotikes

Please take note of the tags.

Hint:

> One animal is used humorously

Hint 2:

> Constructed

Hint 3:

> If I would add another similar animal, the scrambled letters would be "lsaneewatkajswliuoatikeos

Comment: Are there any redundant letters? With 21 letters from almost half the alphabet...

Comment: No, just take note of the [language] tag.

Comment: Using hint 3, the third animal added "aosw". Not sure if this means anything.

Comment: rot13(fbjn vf cbyvfu sbe bjy)

Comment: @poco This... essentially reminds me of... gbxv cban.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

laneeatkajswliuotikes contains:

> [kijetesantakalu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Toki_Pona/kijetesantakalu) (toki pona for raccoon, a specific land animal, sometimes used humorously) and [soweli](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Toki_Pona/soweli) (toki pona) for animal.  The third animal would be waso (bird).
>    These are similar in both "land animal" and that they are in toki pona.
>  99% of the credit goes to user 1357924680a who identified the language.  I went through about 40 conlangs and am embarrassed that I missed that one, as it has been on my mind this week. But seeing waso as the third meant I knew their suspicion was likely right.